# request.security in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

Why in the request I receive data for today and yesterday. Two lines are drawn - for today and for yesterday. But the table only displays the number for today

```
_open1D = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", open)

table.cell(tb, 0, 2, str.tostring(_open1D), text_size = size.normal, text_color = color.white)

l0 = line.new(bar_index[1], _open1D, bar_index[800], _open1D, color=color.gray, extend=extend.none)
Lup = line.new(bar_index[1], _open1D+atr_avg, bar_index[800], _open1D+atr_avg, color=color.red, extend=extend.none)
Ldown = line.new(bar_index[1], _open1D-atr_avg, bar_index[800], _open1D-atr_avg, color=color.green, extend=extend.none)
```

I want to get today's opening line